# What steps are necessary to begin a Q&A contest?

Tags: discussion

As it discussed before [here](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149/can-a-best-qa-contest-help-us-to-improve-this-forum), [here](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326/weekly-question-contests-yes-no-or-maybe) and [here](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351/what-is-our-cutoff-for-taking-action-on-the-activity-level-of-the-site), it seems many established users and also some of our moderators support the idea of commencing a weekly/monthly Q&A contest. So let's do it!

**Question:** How to begin a Q&A contest in this forum? Should our moderators contact the community managers for some cooperation?

**Remark:** This question is **not** about usefulness of such a contest. If you want to discuss on this subject please see the above posts. Here I am asking about the **steps** which are necessary to commence a Q&A contest in MESE.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question (which seems better suited for moderators and community managers) but if you are looking for another SE site that has implemented contests pretty well, codegolf (http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) has certain features that might be applicable (and others that might not be)...

Comment: You paraphrasing the earlier discussion is pretty one-sided, and saying "let us do it" quite weird given that you do not want discussion about it being done or not here.

Comment: @quid: Good point. Perhaps this should be edited to come across as, "IF we were to do it, how should it be done?"

Comment: @brendansullivan07 Yes, I think this would be better.  JPBurke (earlier) already made some edit in that direction that improved the post. Personally I think one should edit still further. (I do not do it myself, as I am rather against that contest, so I might be biased.)